# How do I remove duplicate program in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I did apt-get install qtcreator and it installed qt 4.5.3(qt4.5.2real) I had qt 4.5.2. If I go in Applications->programming I see 2 shortcuts for qtcreator, one of them being newer. How do I remove the older one? On another note, if I want to update Qt to 4.6 what would be the steps if I already have qt 4.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to get rid of the extra shortcut, use `alacarte` to edit the Gnome menus (System > Preferences > Main Menu).  Just go in, figure out which is the extra shortcut (by looking at the Properties for each), and uncheck the box in the "Show" column to remove it.

[image]

If the extra shortcut is an additional *version* of the program and you want to get rid of it, you'll need to see if you can remove the package that installed it.  Gnome and Alacarte gets their information about installed programs from the **.desktop* files in */usr/share/applications*, so check to see if there are multiple *qtcreator*.desktop* files in that directory, and what packages installed them:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/applications/qt*creator*.desktop
```

The next step would be to uninstall the extraneous package, but be careful to uninstall the correct one.

*`dpkg` will fail to find multiple packages if you installed* qtcreator *from source.*

---

Unfortunately I don't know anything about upgrading to Qt 4.6; it might depend on what version of Ubuntu you're using, and how willing you are to get your hands dirty.  Ubuntu Karmic 9.10 does not appear to have Qt 4.6 in the standard repositories, but it may be available elsewhere.

According to [this post on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8420975), Qt 4.6 breaks binary compatibility with 4.5 and so packages that depend on Qt would need to be recompiled to work.  Thus, Qt 4.6 is unlikely to be officially backported.

[This post on arora-dev](http://groups.google.com/group/arora-dev/browse_thread/thread/5c14ac61d168777) gives a PPA: https://edge.launchpad.net/~mapopa/%2Barchive/qt4.6 ... **Use at your own risk.**

The best way to update may be to wait for Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid); it will use Qt 4.6 out of the box.  If you want to help alpha/beta test, you can check out the [latest Alpha2](http://www.ubuntu.com/testing/lucid/alpha2).

Comment: actually I could not find the second package even though it can start.  I did do the update with a diff so maybe both are available at the same time?  I am a bit noob in this department